# Is it possible to pause current thread while JOptionPane is open?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, joptionpane

I'm working on a game in Java, and i'm trying to pause it while JOptionPane confirm box is open. Here is the code:

```
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {

            int dialogResult =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to exit this game? Your progress will not be saved!","Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            //What should i do with this???
            try {
                Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                synchronized(currentThread) {
                    currentThread.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ////
            if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                exitProcedure();
            }
            else {
                if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION || dialogResult == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {

                    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                    synchronized(currentThread) {

                        currentThread.notify();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Is this the right way to do this? What should I do differently to make it work?

Comment: `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` will "pause" then Event Dispatching Thread at the point that the dialog is shown - personally I think you're overthinking the issue - can you. provide an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: In this game i have only this JOptionPane dialog. I have some graphic objects that are moving on the screen (which are redrawn using paintComponent), so when i'm trying to close game window, i get this JOptionPane as I should, and those objects are still moving. Maybe this question is stupid, and I'm considering to skip this part if I could not work it out.

Comment: You need a reference to what ever is updating the state (ie the game thread) and pause it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swing events are handled in the [Event Dispatcher Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and you don't want to pause this thread in any way. It handles all the UI operations like repaint so any pause will make your application unresponsive.

You would have to obtain the reference to the thread which is running the background logic and then pause it. It's most likely not `Thread.currentThread()` although you have not provided the complete source code. You can check the thread type with [`SwingUtils.isEventDispatchThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread--) method.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Swing and the Event Dispatcher Thread know about modal dialogs, like `JOptionPane` and will actually pause the EDT, and then launch a new EDT to service events for the JOptionPane.  It's a complex process but the upshot is that you can call the static methods that make dialogs from `JOptionPane` without fear of blocking the EDT.

Comment: Replace `Thread.currentThread()` with something like `MyGame.getMainLoopThread()` and ideally avoid synchronization by instead using a volatile field e.g. `MyGame.setPaused(true)`. You must not run your game logic or any potentially blocking operation in EDT.